# sqlite in windows runtime component

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

am trying to use sqlite in a windows runtime component. But I get some 219 errors when i add the nuget sqlite-net package. couldnt figure it out anywhere. Any similar issues ?

I finally used a store app class library to use sqlite and called those methods in it from my windows runtime component.

method in store app

```
   public async  Task<IEnumerable<TaskGroup> > GetTaskGroup()
    {
         return await conn.QueryAsync<TaskGroup>("select * from TaskGroup");

    }
```

calling method in win runtime component

```
public IAsyncOperation<IEnumerable<TaskGroup>> GetAllTaskGroup()
    {
        return m_objDAL.GetTaskGroup().AsAsyncOperation();

    }
```

i get the following error

```
Error   1   Method 'Tasker.BAL.TaskManager.GetAllTaskGroup()' has a parameter of type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SQLLite.Models.TaskGroup>>' in its signature. Although this generic type is not a valid Windows Runtime type, the type or its generic parameters implement interfaces that are valid Windows Runtime types. Consider changing the type 'SQLLite.Models.TaskGroup' in the method signature. It is not a valid Windows Runtime parameter type.
```

making the store app method as private resolves it as per this blog
http://rarcher.azurewebsites.net/Post/PostContent/23

but i cant ue this since it will give me access issues since it is private.

any soln ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what these errors are, but did you first install the SQLite for Windows Runtime through Tools > Extensions? sqlite-net is LINQ query library

Answer (score 0):

A Windows runtime component has [many limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx#DeclaringTypes) regarding the types it exposes externally.

When you include `sqlite-net`, all its types are declared public and would effectively become exposed by the component. This is the reson for the errors you are seeing.

You can do one of two things to resolve the problem:

- You can change all `public` modifiers in `SQLite.cs` and `SQLiteAsync.cs` files to internal. This will make it more difficult for you to update the package to a newer version since you'll have to repeat the process every time (a couple of minutes of work).
- You can create a separate Windows Store apps class library, reference `sqlite-net` from there and reference this class library from your Windows runtime component. This way `sqlite-net`'s classes won't be automatically exposed by the component.

Comment: Kindly see my edit to the post..I used the second approach but still get some errors.

Comment: @PrakashR - the error seems to be about one of your classes. Take a look at this link, as it shows you how to define classes for a WRC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077.aspx Hopefully there is something there that will resolve your issue.

Comment: @PrakashR As stated in the error message there's a problem with your class `SQLLite.Models.TaskGroup`. Its public interface does not conform to Windows runtime component requirements. Perhaps you have public fields in that class? For further assistance please post the list of all its public members.

Comment: @DamirArh : yeah.. I had made all its methods as public so that I can access them from my runtime component.