# SQLite in an Universal App

Tags: c#, sqlite, portable-class-library, class-library, win-universal-app

I am developing an Universal App which should use SQLite. 
Additionally I want to store data into the database from a background task (Windows Runtime Component).
Therefore I need to do my hole SQLite stuff in a ClassLibrary because of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631063/sqlite-in-windows-runtime-component).
I also use sqlite-net.

Now I discovered that i need SQLite for [Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a)  and [SQLite for Windows Phone](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a). Or is there another extension which i can use for those two platforms instead?

If I need those two extensions i should create two ClassLibraries. Or am I wrong?
One ClassLibrary where i install SQLite for Windows Phone and reference this library to my Windows Phone project and a second ClassLibrary where I install SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) and reference this library to my Windows Store Project or is there a better way??

Any help is welcome :)

Regards, Markus

Answer (score 1):

**SQLite** now supports better way to work with Universal Application. Just download extension for Visual Studio 2015.
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4913e7d5-96c9-4dde-a1a1-69820d615936

This extension supports IOT too.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite-net is c# code library that bridges the gap between the sqlite.dll which is exposed from the reference to assembly you indicated.

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Answer (score 0):

Create one solution with three projects for **Windows**, **Windows Phone**, and the **shared** **PCL**. The SQLite extension will be added to the correspoding Windows and Windows Phone project. The whole SQL stuff like your tables/models will be added to your Portable Class Libary.